# Number in Number-squared

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Consider a sequence of natural numbers for which N appears as a substring in N^2. [A018834](https://oeis.org/A018834)

Output the `n`th element of this sequence.

#### Rules

Program takes only `n` as input and outputs just one number - `N`.

The sequence can be 0-indexed or 1-indexed.

```
Sequence: 1 5 6 10 25 50 60 76 100 250 376 500 600 625 760 ...
Squares:  1 25 36 100 625 2500 3600 5776 10000 62500 141376 250000 360000 390625 577600 ...
```

This is **code-golf** so shortest code wins.

Comment: Is there any upper limit on the input?

Comment: @maxb No, for larger inputs, it should theoretically output the value.

Comment: A lot of implementations will run into problems (for me its due to not being able to create arrays with more than 2^32 values), which will make most solutions bound to a maximum size by default. Should these solutions be disqualified?

Comment: @maxb I think _theoretically_ was meant as _not necessarily practically_.

Comment: @Arnauld the problem for my specific implementation was that I had an 8-byter which would solve until `n=9`, because create an array with 10^(input) values and filter it.

Comment: @maxb Normally limitations such as that are ignored if an implementation on hardware with, say, arbitrarily large integer sizes and memory quantity would function as expected with all inputs. (posted before the response - limited to 9 is low even in this case).

Comment: @Ourous I know it's really low, that's why I don't like my solution. I could add a byte and have it work for much bigger inputs, so I'll add that as an alternative

Comment: "N appears in N^2" would be better worded as something like "the decimal digits of N is a [contiguous] substring of the decimal digits of N squared" (11 does not "appear in" 121). [Strictly "contiguous" is redundant, but adding it is clear.]

Comment: @JonathanAllan Alternate suggested rewording: "N is lexicographically present in N^2"

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{(grep {$^a²~~/$a/},1..*)[$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ojvSi1QKFaJS7x0Ka6On2VRP1aHUM9PS3NaJX42Nr/xYmVCmkacYammtb/AQ)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                            }  # Anonymous code block that returns
 (                      )[$_]   # The nth index of
  grep {          },1..*        # Filtering from the natural numbers
        $^a²                    # If the square of the number
            ~~/$a/              # Contains the number
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

1-indexed

```
µNNnNå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0FY/vzy/w0v//zc0BAA)

**Explanation**

```
µ         # loop over increasing N until counter equals input
 N        # push N (for the output)
  Nn      # push N^2
    N     # push N
     å    # push N in N^2
          # if true, increase counter
```

Comment: That `µ` command is just... I wish I had that.

Comment: @maxb: It is quite practical for challenges where you need to find the `Nth` number that meets a specific condition.

Comment: "**if true**, increase counter"?

Comment: @JonathanAllan: As in, "If N is contained in N^2 increase the value of the counter by 1". I should probably have written "increment counter".

Comment: I actually didn't understand the explanation; it appears that if `å` yields true then we have the current `N` at the top of the stack (increment counter and increment `N`), but if not we continue (increment `N`). Maybe use something other than "`N`" since that is the final result in the question body :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Maybe adding and example of the stack content would help visualize.I don't really see the issue. After `å` is executed we have its result on the top of the stack and **N** under it. If `å` was true the program ends and **N** is displayed. If was false, the next iteration begins and the previous **N** gets left on the stack (but ignored).

Comment: The problems I had were 1) loop N vs N from the question and 2) thinking about stacks is not natural for me. I think it does make sense but would suggest x rather than N for the incrementing variable (and maybe label the counter something like i?)

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Ah OK, I didn't reflect on fact that `N` had a special meaning in the question. In my explanation, `N` always mean "current loop index". The counter is only mentioned as "counter". I'll see if I can reword it in a way that makes it clearer. The reason I call it `N` instead of `x` is that it is referred to as `N` in all 05AB1E documentation and calling it something else would be confusing (imo).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,k=0)=>n?f(n-!!(++k*k+'').match(k),k):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxLEkRADADQq8RKIihjOTRn6erR8wmJasr1e6ze7v385Y@QvvvZqL2WnKNDrcV15CadI2pTFMgslXBZUrv5M3xQqBZ6So6WUMHBYwCFEfrulpkgmB62Lu1qb7wLovwH)

---

## Non-recursive version, 47 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(k=0;n-=!!(++k*k+'').match(k););k")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrNDoIwDADgVylcaG0gmHib9V2WufnT2RIgvP7U03f53vGIW1pfyz6a33Mr0kxu@YgV@@IrqszBRuk6ZNaT8jDQ9Il7eqJSoKA9tX8zEDgHMLjCZf7JTJDcNq95qv7AgkbUvg)

Comment: This gives up to `n=23` only?

Comment: @VedantKandoi It depends on the size of the call stack in your JS engine. But computing \$a(n)\$ requires \$a(n)\$ recursions, so that's \$7600\$ recursive calls for \$n=23\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes (works for any input in theory, but only for `n<10` in practice)

```
úrgÉ²ï╧§
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7pyZ8OJwrLDr@KVp8Kn//8y)

### Alternative (works for `n<49` in practice and theory)

```
►rgÉ²ï╧§
```

The only difference is that instead of creating a list with `10^(input)` values, I create a list with `10^6` items. This takes a while to run, so you could swap the first byte to any other 1-byte literal to test it out.

### Explanation

```
ú          pop(a), push(10**a)
 r         range(0, n)
  g        filter array by...
   É       start block of length 3
    ²      pop a : push(a*a)
     ï     index of current loop
      ╧    pop a, b, a.contains(b)
           Block ends here
       §   get from array
```

The reason why this solution doesn't handle large input is that I noticed that the sequence grows less than exponentially, but more than any polynomial. That's why I used the `10**n` operator (I wanted to use `2**n` but it failed for input 1). That means that I create an extremely large array even for small inputs, just to filter out the vast majority of it, and then take one of the first elements. It's extremely wasteful, but I couldn't find another way to do it without increasing the byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 95 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(do((i 0))((= n 0)i)(if(search(format()"~d"(incf i))(format()"~d"(* i i)))(decf n))))
```

[Try it  online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCsIwEER/ZQgIE0Go3vVfYtLgQpMtac759bgFL95m38y@uMmxT26qO7I2CHLTgju64rEgKWi4hI4ONwJuL4wwLs6GtLdQ3imweiYlBYv35BPVgnhK5rGGFj8/Bb0byVFqzBBb/tGrGQ2aabW6WvLzvOcX)

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
@aJ±X²søY}f
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QGFKsViyc/hZfWY=&input=OA==)

```
È²søY «U´}a
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=yLJz+Fkgq1W0fWE=&input=OA==)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 83 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
```

```
(!!)[i\\i<-[1..]|indexOf(""<+i)(""<+i^2)>=0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r0wnJLWi5H9aaV5ySWZ@noKtgoaiomZ0ZkxMpo1utKGeXmxNZl5KaoV/moaSko12piaEijPStLM1iOUKLkkEmmQLNLdAAW4GSJupQez/f8lpOYnpxf91PX3@u1TmJeZmJkM4ATmJJWn5RbkA)

```
(!!)                               // index into the list of
 [ i                               // i for every
  \\ i <- [1..]                    // i from 1 upwards
  | indexOf (""<+i) (""<+i^2) >= 0 // where i is in the square of i
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 63 bytes

```java
n->{int r=0;for(;!(++r*r+"").contains(r+"")||--n>0;);return r;}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Shaggy*.
-2 bytes thanks to *@Arnauld*.

1-indexed.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY/BDoIwDIbvPkXltLlA1MSLE99ALh7Vw5xohlhIV0yM8uy4oZc2/dt@7V@Zp0mry32wtfEedsbhewLgkEu6GltCEctRACtiRKmD0k9C8GzYWSgAIYcB0@07DlA@19eGhJ4KpWhGKklkZhvkwPZiLD@fNMXtXEtNJXeEQLofdES23bkOyD/52bgLPMKe2DM5vB1OYOTvoXghXnP5QoPb5MtVSErJsQmwf3kuH1nTcdaGTa5ROJWsj5wozIIR@XfRD18)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int r=0;          //  Result-integer, starting at 0
  for(;             //  Loop as long as:
       !(++r*r+"")  //    (increase result `r` by 1 first with `++r`)
                    //    If the square of the result `r` (as String) 
        .contains(  //    does not contain
          r+"")||   //    the result `r` itself (as String):
       --n>0;);     //     (decrease input `n` by 1 first with `--n`)
                    //     And continue looping if input `n` is not 0 yet
  return r;}        //  Return the result `r`
```

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##LU8xDsIwDNx5hdUpIWpVkFgIgRfAwggMIRSUUlzkuEgI9e0lKSy27mzf@Wr7snl9uQ@usSHA1nr8TAA8ckVX6yrYJTgS4ESqKHVk@kksgS17BztAMDBgvv6kBTKlvrYkNK5LLTE3QimaksoyWbgWOVoEMcLNbFlqqrgjBNL9oJPoszs3UfSv/Wr9BR7xROyZPN4OJ7Dy91LySH7ezDT4lZkvYlNKjkOA/Ttw9SjajotnvOQGhVfZ8siZwiJGkf8c/fAF)

Comment: @Shaggy Ah, of course. Thanks!

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, smart way of combining the loop and if! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1ẇ²$#Ṫ
```

1-indexed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w4a72Q5tUlB/uXPUfyDMFAA)**

#### How?

Finds the first `n` of the sequence as a list and then yields the tail, `N`.

```
1ẇ²$#Ṫ - Link: integer, n (>0)
1      - initialise x to 1
    #  - collect the first n matches, incrementing x, where:
   $   -   last two links as a monad:
  ²    -     square x
 ẇ     -     is (x) a substring of (x²)?
       -     (implicitly gets digits for both left & right arguments when integers)
     Ṫ - tail
```

---

If `0` were considered a Natural number we could use the 1-indexed full-program [`ẇ²$#Ṫ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrvZDm1SUH@5c9f@/oRkA) for 5.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```ruby
->n,i=1{/#{i+=1}/=~"#{i*i}"&&n-=1while n>0;i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ9PWsFpfuTpT29awVt@2TgnI1MqsVVJTy9O1NSzPyMxJVcizM7DOrP2vYaCnZ2SgqZeamJxRXZNZU6CQFp0ZW/sfAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 81 bytes

```clj
(fn[n](nth(filter #(clojure.string/includes?(str(* % %))(str %))(range))n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCoNAEAS/0hCEGQ/JyZMHyTuCh7AZ15VllHF9/zrRUxVNQYe8LodJpc2SlqygSpN@dCQtM00pFzE8KNzZcy@exVfSkI@f7AP5QC0aNMx/v2hfjeL0CsrMtQMzerwtYhY/OwE) (Unfortunately, TIO doesn't seem to support Clojure's standard string library)

If Clojure had shorter importing syntax, or had a `includes?` method in the core library, this could actually be somewhat competitive. `clojure.string/includes?` alone is longer than some answers here though :/

```clj
(defn nth-sq-subs [n]
  (-> ; Filter from an infinite range of numbers the ones where the square of
      ;  the number contains the number itself
    (filter #(clojure.string/includes? (str (* % %)) (str %))
            (range))

    ; Then grab the "nth" result. Inc(rementing) n so 0 is skipped, since apparently
    ;  that isn't in the sequence
    (nth (inc n))))
```

Since the TIO link is broken, here's a test run. The number on the left is the index (`n`), and the result (`N`) is on the right:

```clj
(mapv #(vector % (nth-sq-subs %)) (range 100))
=>
[[0 1]
 [1 5]
 [2 6]
 [3 10]
 [4 25]
 [5 50]
 [6 60]
 [7 76]
 [8 100]
 [9 250]
 [10 376]
 [11 500]
 [12 600]
 [13 625]
 [14 760]
 [15 1000]
 [16 2500]
 [17 3760]
 [18 3792]
 [19 5000]
 [20 6000]
 [21 6250]
 [22 7600]
 [23 9376]
 [24 10000]
 [25 14651]
 [26 25000]
 [27 37600]
 [28 50000]
 [29 60000]
 [30 62500]
 [31 76000]
 [32 90625]
 [33 93760]
 [34 100000]
 [35 109376]
 [36 250000]
 [37 376000]
 [38 495475]
 [39 500000]
 [40 505025]
 [41 600000]
 [42 625000]
 [43 760000]
 [44 890625]
 [45 906250]
 [46 937600]
 [47 971582]
 [48 1000000]
 [49 1093760]
 [50 1713526]
 [51 2500000]
 [52 2890625]
 [53 3760000]
 [54 4115964]
 [55 5000000]
 [56 5050250]
 [57 5133355]
 [58 6000000]
 [59 6250000]
 [60 6933808]
 [61 7109376]
 [62 7600000]
 [63 8906250]
 [64 9062500]
 [65 9376000]
 [66 10000000]
 [67 10050125]
 [68 10937600]
 [69 12890625]
 [70 25000000]
 [71 28906250]
 [72 37600000]
 [73 48588526]
 [74 50000000]
 [75 50050025]
 [76 60000000]
 [77 62500000]
 [78 66952741]
 [79 71093760]
 [80 76000000]
 [81 87109376]
 [82 88027284]
 [83 88819024]
 [84 89062500]
 [85 90625000]
 [86 93760000]
 [87 100000000]
 [88 105124922]
 [89 109376000]
 [90 128906250]
 [91 146509717]
 [92 177656344]
 [93 200500625]
 [94 212890625]
 [95 250000000]
 [96 250050005]
 [97 289062500]
 [98 370156212]
 [99 376000000]]
```

This should be able to support any value of `n`; providing you're willing to wait for it to finish (finding the 50th to 100th integers in the sequence took like 15 minutes). Clojure supports arbitrarily large integer arithmetic, so once numbers start getting huge, it starts using `BigInt`s.

Answer (score 1):

### **Edit (response to comments): Python 2, 76 bytes**

Wanted to try for a non recursive method. (New to golfing, any tips would be great!)

```
def f(c,n=0):
    while 1:
        if`n`in`n*n`:
            if c<2:return n
            c-=1
        n+=1
```

Thanks both BMO and Vedant Kandoi!

Comment: You don't have to count `print(f(13))` in the code. Also `while 1:`,`if c==1:return n`,`c==1 can be c<2`

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that you wanted a non-recursive version, nvm.. Anyway, I currently count 76 bytes not 79.

Comment: And you can save a few more: The spaces before & after `\`` are redundant and the one after `c<2:` too, next you can mix tabs and spaces for indentation (as shown [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58/48198)): [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYxBCsMgFAXX8RR/qWkCNd1JPUsMRvFDeRFRQk9v3AyzGCb/a7qw9X6GSFH6BfatjKA78S@QHkYcHRzDYYYzYuJI/ruZEmorIIjJr1aPDC@rey6MOj6Dshz3zsitSqVU158H "Python 2 – Try It Online") Btw. there is no need to keep your old version (it's in the edit history for those who are interested) and why not link to TIO (or similar)/use the template from there?

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔¹ηＷθ«≦⊕η¿№Ｉ×ηηＩη≦⊖θ»Ｉη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLsbg4Mz1Pw1BHIQPIK8/IzElVAEooVHNx@iYWQGU985KLUnNT80pSUyDqODPTFDSc80vzSjScE4tLNEIyc1OLNTJAkpo6CmAhIEtTAWGESyqSESCLa7kCijJh@oGKrf//N/@vW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔¹η
```

Start `N` at 1. (Or, this could start counting at `0` which would make the input 1-indexed.)

```
Ｗθ«
```

Repeat until we have found `n` numbers in the sequence.

```
≦⊕η
```

Increment `N`.

```
¿№Ｉ×ηηＩη
```

If `N*N` contains `N`, then...

```
≦⊖θ»
```

... decrement `n`.

```
Ｉη
```

Print `N`.

My attempts at golfing this further were stymied by Charcoal a) not having an `if..then` except at the end of a block (which costs 2 bytes) b) not having a `Contains` operator (converting the output of `Find` or `Count` into a boolean that I could subtract from `n` again costs 2 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>47</s> 43 bytes

<sup>-4 bytes thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) (adding 1 to recursive call instead of returning `n-1`)</sup>

```python
f=lambda c,n=1:c and-~f(c-(`n`in`n*n`),n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixDsIgEAbg3ae48c7SAQeHJn0WOaEoif1LCEZc@uq03/jlf31vuPUe54@uz6DkDWY7eVKEcY/sR3ZwCQ5XODEYrPS4FWqUQEXxWtiahMpFf4@E/K0sItOFcjmXmoncpNv7AQ)

### Explantion/Ungolfed

Recursive function taking two arguments \$c,n\$; \$n\$ is counts up \$1,2,3\dots\$ and everytime \$n \texttt{ in } n^2\$ it decrements \$c\$. The recursion ends as soon as \$c = 0\$:

```python
# Enumerating elements of A018834 in reverse starting with 1
def f(counter, number=1):
    # Stop counting
    if counter == 0:
        return 0
    # Number is in A018834 -> count 1, decrement counter & continue
    elif `number` in `number ** 2`:
        return f(counter-1, number+1) + 1
    # Number is not in A018834 -> count 1, continue
    else:
        return f(counter, number+1) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 60 bytes

```
([n^2|n<-[1..],elem(show n)$words=<<mapM(:" ")(show$n^2)]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyM6L86oJs9GN9pQTy9WJzUnNVejOCO/XCFPU6U8vyil2NbGJjexwFfDSklBSRMspQLUoRmrqKj5PzcxM0/BVgEkr6BRUJSZV6KXpqkQbaCnZ2gS@/9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

```
      n<-[1..]              -- loop n through all numbers starting with 1
 [n^2|        ,    ]        -- collect the n^2 in a list where
     elem(show n)           -- the string representation of 'n' is in the list
       words ... (show$n^2) -- which is constructed as follows:

            show$n^2        -- turn n^2 into a string, i.e. a list of characters
          (:" ")            -- a point free functions that appends a space
                            -- to a character, e.g.  (:" ") '1' -> "1 "
        mapM                -- replace each char 'c' in the string (n^2) with
                            -- each char from (:" ") c and make a list of all
                            -- combinations thereof.
                            -- e.g. mapM (:" ") "123" -> ["123","12 ","1 3","1  "," 23"," 2 ","  3","   "]
      words=<<              -- split each element into words and flatten to a single list
                            -- example above -> ["123","12","1","3","1","23","2","3"]

(                      !!)  -- pick the element at the given index
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```apl
1∘{>⍵:⍺-1⋄(⍺+1)∇⍵-∨/(⍕⍺)⍷⍕⍺×⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/3/BRx4xqu0e9W60e9e7SNXzU3aIBZGgbaj7qaAeK6j7qWKEPFJkKFNR81Lsdwjo8HUjU/k971DaBAv1c1Y/6pgKNACrTUUhTAFK1h1YY6Dzq3Wz6HwA)

0-indexed.

Comment: `(⍕⍺)⍷⍕` → `⍺⍷⍥⍕`

Comment: I knew there was something I could do with that...

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 33 bytes

```perl
map{1while++$\**2!~/${\}/}1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saDasDwjMydVW1slRkvLSLFOX6U6pla/1lBPTyW@tvr/f5N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usWAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <strike>137</strike> <strike>123</strike> 79 bytes

*-thanks @Jo King for 44 bytes*

```lua
n=io.read()i=0j=0while(i-n<0)do j=j+1i=i+(n.find(j*j,j)and 1or 0)end
print(j*j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fck7CoAwDADQ3VN0bPyUdDeHKaRiQkmlKB4/4ltfe4q7kfQ0auEIQqiE7ymtRtlsR@AelHTJQrJES4cYR511VSjGIfcREKrxdA2x@x9wz/gB)

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fck7CoAwDADQ3VN0bPyUdDeHKaRiQkmlKB4/4ltfe4q7kfQ0auEIQqiE7ymtRtlsR@AelHTJQrJES4cYR511VSjGIfcREKrxdA2x@x9wz/gB). Some generic tips; `false/true` can be `0>1`/`0<1`, brackets aren't necessary for `if`s and `while`s, you can remove most whitespace after numbers (even newlines).

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 82 bytes

```
proc S n {while 1 {if {[regexp [incr i] [expr $i**2]]&&[incr j]==$n} {return $i}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYo7DoMwDIav8g@Igal0zykYI0@RW4wgRG5QK1k@e4qEGL9HTWtrRfeECRn2nWVljDB5waLym38FUXJSCCGepOhkGJ5EfX/5hULossOU66H5zO7eqmwMK0f9IE64T3KMj/YH)

Comment: I think you can mix the while and the if with:
`proc S n {while {[incr j [regexp [incr i] [expr $i**2]]]-$n} {};return $i}`

Answer (score 0):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 24 bytes

```
{x:str(x)in'~.x^2}from N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8lMqfyfpmBl@7@6wqq4pEijQjMzT71OryLOqDatKD9Xwe9/fmmJRpqGgaaOQpqGEZg0NNDU5CrOyC/XSNNRMDTV/A8A)

Returns a lazy list which, when called like a function, returns the `n`th element in the series.

### Explanation

```
{x:str(x)in'~.x^2}from N
{x:              }from N       select all natural numbers `x` such that
   str(x)                      the string representation of `x`
         in                    is contained in
           '~.x^2              "~" + str(x^2)
```