# Self-contained powers

Tags: code-golf, number

Given integer `n`, output the smallest exponent `e` greater than 1 such that `n^e` contains `n` as a substring.

For example, for `25`, the answer should be `2`, as `25 ^ 2 = 625`, which contains `25` as a substring, but the answer for `13` should be `10`, as `13 ^ 10 = 137858491849`, so `10` is the lowest exponent for which the result contains `13` as a substring.

## Rules

- Standard I/O rules
- Standard loopholes apply
- Shortest code in bytes wins
- `n` will always be an integer greater than `0`

## Test Cases

```
1 => 2   (1 ^ 2 = 1)
2 => 5   (2 ^ 5 = 32)
3 => 5   (3 ^ 5 = 243)
4 => 3   (4 ^ 3 = 64)
5 => 2   (5 ^ 2 = 25)
6 => 2   (6 ^ 2 = 36)
7 => 5   (7 ^ 5 = 16807)
8 => 5   (8 ^ 5 = 32768)
9 => 3   (9 ^ 3 = 729)
10 => 2  (10 ^ 2 = 100)
11 => 11 (11 ^ 11 = 285311670611)
12 => 14 (12 ^ 14 = 1283918464548864)
13 => 10 (13 ^ 10 = 137858491849)
14 => 8  (14 ^ 8 = 1475789056)
15 => 26 (15 ^ 26 = 3787675244106352329254150390625)
16 => 6  (16 ^ 6 = 16777216)
17 => 17 (17 ^ 17 = 827240261886336764177)
18 => 5  (18 ^ 5 = 1889568)
19 => 11 (19 ^ 11 = 116490258898219)
20 => 5  (20 ^ 5 = 3200000)
25 => 2  (25 ^ 2 = 625)
30 => 5  (30 ^ 5 = 24300000)
35 => 10 (35 ^ 10 = 2758547353515625)
40 => 3  (40 ^ 3 = 64000)
45 => 5  (45 ^ 5 = 184528125)
50 => 2  (50 ^ 2 = 2500)
55 => 11 (55 ^ 11 = 13931233916552734375)
60 => 2  (60 ^ 2 = 3600)
65 => 17 (65 ^ 17 = 6599743590836592050933837890625)
70 => 5  (70 ^ 5 = 1680700000)
75 => 3  (75 ^ 3 = 421875)
80 => 5  (80 ^ 5 = 3276800000)
85 => 22 (85 ^ 22 = 2800376120856162211833149645328521728515625)
90 => 3  (90 ^ 3 = 729000)
95 => 13 (95 ^ 13 = 51334208327950511474609375)
100 => 2 (100 ^ 2 = 10000)
```

[Python script](https://tio.run/##TU@7bsMwDJzNrzgECCAlHux0K@As/Yw@gKCRbAIxZUhy23y9SqUeOpAgj8c7crnnKchTKT6GGemewPMSYsYljl9EV@fhWa6czY99poYx4ETN98Q3h5SjopCQwfLX4XAAV6IyjwN6aqLLaxQw0aS7LNlU5df@3eKoc/4PnhRkj62GuyWnFFpiZexewiqZZcS6IAfsU3Vl@YxudpITglfsTXbYw0ytnmGJfIioJMSLjM5wi8dED3RqvH0mlprNQ0WHc5U2Gh@1GDTZh6a0cC22XB911pZS@q7rSv8L) to generate the first 1000 answers

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176685/number-in-number-squared)

Comment: [A045537](http://oeis.org/A045537)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 31 bytes

```
{$^a;first {$a**$_~~/$a/},2..*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbRCkAwFAbgV/nTSax1zMSNeBRrF1aKaNxo5tXHd/Uds1@7tN3IHYYUaLK9W/x5IZAVgsz7VmSrKDWziOm0NzIyGEYEBzIxg9s9nqJm1qqU/3QrG8XMtVJl@gA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>69</s> 44 bytes

```r
function(n,i=2){while(!grepl(n,n^i))i=i+1;i}
```

Anonymous function. Works on large `i` when `n` is converted to BigZ (see TIO). Thanks for teaching me something Giuseppe and digEmAll!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwEEX3OcWImwRFqCAI0qsIaZ2mA@00zEwRFc8e05XwN@/B40vZg42kUMfYo2qUF9gCOWo1EBU6Sm@I/ABdc17ENgHEhglFIQrZOKNR7ybqpNY@zTk454a2DCv3Rgt7PlJ7Dp/nSBP6XRLMU3V8pxCopUNzo28ZfNTTduavlxDcH5uK5Qc)

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTyfT1kizujwjMydVQzG9KLUgR8M@T8c@Ly5TUzPTNlPb0Do5sUQjU7OWK8E@wbYgsbgk9X@ahoWp5n8A) -- you had an extra space in `n, ?n^i` and `paste` converts to `character` by default :-)

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTyfT1kizujwjMydVQzG9KLUgR8M@T8c@Ly5TUzPTNlPb0DqzlivBPsG2ILG4JPV/moaFqeZ/AA) -- returning `i` should be sufficient.

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTyfT1kizujwjMydVQzG9KLUgByiWF5epqZlpm6ltaJ1Z@z9Nw8JU8z8A "R – Try It Online") paste is not necessary, grepl converts to character by default :)

Comment: The problem is that it is "faulty" when exponents become big because of floating points accuracy and the fact that big numbers are converted to string in scientific notation. For instance 15 returns 17 while it should be 26. So, theoretically this works, but in practice we should use a Big Integer package or something like that...

Comment: @digEmAll I always forget that `grep` and friends do that...

Comment: @digEmAll for BigInt you could just force input to be a bigInt like BigZ from gmp and it should still work, except possibly for converting `i` to a bigZ as well

Comment: @Giuseppe: yep, using gmp works like a charm (no need to convert `i`) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwEEX3OcWImwRFqCAI0qsIaZ2mA@00zEwRFc8e05XwN@/B40vZg42kUMfYo2qUF9gCOWo1EBU6Sm@I/ABdc17ENgHEhglFIQrZOKNR7ybqpNY@zTk454a2DCv3Rgt7PlJ7Dp/nSBP6XRLMU3V8pxCopUNzo28ZfNTTduavlxDcH5uK5Qc "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6 / Node.js),  <s>41</s>  40 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

Takes input as a *Number* (works for \$n<15\$) or a *[BigInt](https://v8.dev/blog/bigint)* literal.

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>`${x*=n}`.match(n)?2:-~g(x))(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBDoIwEAC/sgcOuzQQ5KgufqVNpVWDuwSIaULw67XeZpKZl/u41S/PeWtE72MOnIUHjJx4sNWeapbDtm@3@QcK3fpz842YiIrkoAsKMJzkAgLXAl33R2MIvMqq09hOGtE6rHY5qKQWDITyUv4B)

Comment: Ended up with a solution very similar to yours for [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k4j3bbC1i5BpbpCyzavNkEvN7EkOUMjT9PeyEq3Ll2jQlMTyPmfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpmGhqfkfAA)

Comment: @Shaggy You need to use big integers, otherwise it wont return the correct answer in some test cases. At the end it has the same bytecount `n=>(g=x=>`${x*=n}`.match(n)?2n:-~g(x))(n)`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz, generally we don't need to worry about precision issues but it will work with BigInts too.

Comment: Minor thing but if this uses BigInt shouldn't the title be JavaScript (Node.js)? ES6 doesn't have BigInt yet.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto You're right. My initial intention was to explain that it works with either a Number or a BigInt. Now clarified.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 17 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Erik the Outgolfer*

*-6 bytes thanks to @ngn*

*thanks to @H.PWiz for making the code not require a custom `⎕pp` (print precision)*

```apl
⊢⍟×⍣(∨/(⍕÷)⍷0⍕⊣)⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HXoke98w9Pf9S7WONRxwp9jUe9Uw9v13zUu90AyHrUtRjIXPE/7VHbhEe9fY@6mg@tN37UNvFR39TgIGcgGeLhGfw/TcGQK03BCIiNgdgUiC2A2BAkaAjmmXIBAA)

```apl
⊢⍟×⍣(∨/(⍕÷)⍷0⍕⊣)⍨
  ×⍣(          )⍨ generates a geometric progression by repeatedly multiplying the argument
                   by its original value
     ∨/(⍕÷)⍷0⍕⊣   the progression stops when this function, applied between the new and the
                   last old member, returns true
         ÷        the original argument (ratio between two consecutive members)
        ⍕         formatted as a string
           ⍷      occurrences within...
            0⍕    ...the formatted (with 0 digits after the decimal point)...
              ⊣   ...new member
     ∨/           are there any?
⊢⍟                use logarithm to determine what power of ⍵ we reached
```

Comment: This fails for 17 because it it finds `17` in  17^14=1.6837782655940093E17, but idk to what precision answers should support

Comment: @Cowsquack I just have to arbitrarily adjust `⎕PP` I guess

Comment: Oh wait that won't even work

Comment: [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtglGBv@rH3Ws0Nd41Dv1Ue8uzUe92yEsrUe9W62A@FF3C5D3qKMdyNY2rH3UMcPofxpQ46PePqAZnv6PupoPrTd@1DYRyAsOcgaSIR6ewf/TFAy50hSMgNgYiE2B2AKIDUGChmCeKRcA).

Comment: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtglGBv8f9U6tNtR@1LtY41HHCv1Hvbse9W5/1DEDKPyod6vWo67Fmoa1j7oW/U8DKn/U2wfU6en/qKv50HrjR20TgbzgIGcgGeLhGfw/TcGQK03BCIiNgdgUiC2A2BAkaAjmmXIBAA)

Comment: @ngn ...that's amazing. I also honestly have no idea what half of it does. But  `1+⍣` is ingenious.

Comment: here's an even [shorter one](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qQMCjtglGBv8fdS161Dv/8PRHvYs1HnWs0Nd41Dv18HbNR73bH3XMALIfdS0Gclb8TwMqf9TbB9Tp6f@oq/nQeuNHbROBvOAgZyAZ4uEZ/D9NwZArTcEIiI2B2BSILYDYECRoCOaZcgEA) but it requires a more modest `⎕pp` because of floating point (im-)precision

Comment: @ngn Feel free to edit in an explanation if you want because I'm just cowering in awe rn :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
f}`Q`^QT2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P602ITAhLjDE6P9/Q2MA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to [Ørjan Johansen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66041/%C3%98rjan-johansen) (returning `y` directely)</sup>

```python
f=lambda x,y=2:y*(`x`in`x**y`)or f(x,y+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYo7DsMgDED3nsLKZFMGyBiJXqVQJSSWWgchosDpKeP7pFaOU@beo/uG32cNUHVz89IU@upZfFWqeTozRBzlaanHAQwskIPsG1rNUjCH@82SroJEY1oekPLwwHoC94JJR2Tq1pg/)

### Explanation/Ungolfed

Recursive function trying from \$2,3\dots\$ until we succeed:

```python
# Start recursion with y=2
def f(x,y=2):
    # If we succeed, we arrived at the desired y
    if `x` in `x**y`:
        return y
    # Else we try with next y
    else:
        return f(x, y+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU4xksIwDOx5xQ5pbM4FobwZrqO4mgcQTyJfNHPjZBSFxK8PNtCxjVbaXUlj0n6Ip22rcFUvCqF2lomHiIW1Rzqfdh0FBLO6zO33DhkVfgMWwjS3LVHnCvcifKcOXqE9oaOJJbfpGeCAZm3AMZfDITWvNQVCOkt82ypc/icq21TS64FIq75VytpHsDyG9FXbLQwCLifExz8yteOoRvxy4zjOaqzNphwfJc/Bbo/zD/YuGLZbfTw@AA)

Comment: [Returning y is shorter](https://tio.run/##DYo7DsMgDED3nsLKZFMGyBiJXqVQJSSWWgchosDpKeP7pFaOU@beo/uG32cNUHVz89IU@upZfFWqeTozRBzlaanHAQwskIPsG1rNUjCH@82SroJEY1oekPLwwHoC94JJR2Tq1pg/ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Weird, I thought I tried that, not exactly sure what I missed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had to swap the multiplication to avoid a space, maybe that was it?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Probably that was it, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
∞>.Δm¹å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8O71zU3IP7Ty89P9/C1MA)

Explanation:

```
∞>.Δm¹å  //full program
∞        //push infinite list, stack = [1,2,3...]
 >       //increment, stack is now [2,3,4...]
  .Δ     //find the first item N that satisfies the following
     ¹   //input
      å  //is in
    m    //(implicit) input **  N
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
;.^s?∧ℕ₂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/31ovrtj@UcfyRy1THzU1/f9vaPQ/CgA)

#### Explanation

```
;.^         Input ^ Output…
   s?       …contains the Input as a substring…
     ∧      …and…
      ℕ₂    …the Output is in [2,+∞)
```

Answer (score 2):

**SAS, <s>71</s> 66 bytes**

Edit: Removed `;run;` at the end, since it's implied by the end of inputs.

```
data a;input n;e=1;do until(find(cat(n**e),cat(n)));e+1;end;cards;
```

Input data is entered after the `cards;` statement, like so:

```
data a;input n;e=1;do until(find(cat(n**e),cat(n)));e+1;end;cards;
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Generates a dataset `a` containing the input `n` and the output `e`.

[image]

Comment: This looks to be a function definition, or equivalent (I assume actually a "macro") This means that requiring it be called with arguments (ie `%p(n)`) is totally fine, however output depends on whether `macro`s in SAS can return values. If they can return, the "output" should be by returning the result, otherwise it should output it by whatever standard output method is supported

Comment: @Skidsdev Thanks for the feedback! SAS is a bit weird; macros aren't really functions, they're just a text substitution language that generates 'real' SAS code when compiled. I had a look at how other people have done I/O for SAS in codegolf, and edited my answer based on that, getting rid of the macro statements.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
2ẇ*¥@1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4a52rUNLHQyV////b2gKAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 99 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text,Data.Integer
$n=hd[p\\p<-[fromInt 2..]|indexOf(""<+n)(""<+prod(repeatn p n))>=0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwFEV3vyKUDi22RQU361SHgqBQt7bDo0lqIHkJ8SkV/HZjUafL4cC5gxaAwVh@14IZUBiUcdYTa4gf8JFdxERZBQRFjSRG4Rcxllfeuq5zu7yV3ppZsE1R9C@FXEwnmUTRbonpd5y3PPHCCSBkjmGa7stVHxqC@aJkMUvI/sNsvU3De5AaxlvI62OonghGDT84ayBpvfkA)

If it doesn't need to work for giant huge numbers, then

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 64 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
$n=hd[p\\p<-[2..]|indexOf(""<+n)(""<+n^p)>=0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r0wnJLWihEslzzYjJbogJqbARjfaSE8vtiYzLyW1wj9NQ0nJRjtPE0LFFWja2RrE/g8uSQTqt1VQUTA0/v8vOS0nMb34v66nz3@XyrzE3MxkCCcgJ7EkLb8oFwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 84 bytes

Takes input as a String representing the number and outputs an int.

Most of the bytes come from the verbosity of the `BigDecimal` being needed to process the large numbers.

```java
n->{int i=1;while(!(new java.math.BigDecimal(n).pow(++i)+"").contains(n));return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BboJAEIbP8hRTThB@ya6wAiV6aHqtF4@Nhy2iroWFwKppDM9OV0NvncNOMv83k2/P8irnTVvq8/57bC9flSqoqGTf04dUmu6OQ7amoDfS2Ka0KbuDLEraWICmmhgbkva2plP6SNrPn/ngzJ59OrAhTSsa9Xx9f@BqxfPbSVWl9@Lp8kZn6xTW0pzCN3V8LwtVy8rTftg2Ny8IlB@4rh8WjTbWsLeBn3eluXSaVD6M@X/G10btqbb4JPa5I9kde9/qzw5N96cr6fU5/2S7sG8rZTwXru9b6HFy@9Obsg6biwlbi5tKe5ICcmm@tk9AOrQDK@PMhunTzjCOHAtEiCGwRIIUGTgD5@AL8Ag8BhfgS/AEPAXPsGBYCEQMkUDMEAsIBmG3GZYCCUMikDKkAhlDZncZ@wU)

---

**How it works**

This is fairly simple but I'll include the explanation for posterity;

```java
n->{                                    // Lamdba taking a String and returning an int
    int i=1;                            // Initialises the count
    while(!                             // Loops and increments until
        (new java.math.BigDecimal(n)    // Creates a new BigDecimal from the input n
            .pow(++i)+"")               // Raises it to the power of the current count
            .contains(n)                // If that contains the input, end the loop
    );
    return i;                           // Return the count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP 49 bytes

```
f(n)=e=1;until(#strsplit(Str(n^e++),Str(n))>1,);e
```

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNw3TNPI0bVNtDa1L80oyczSUi0uKigtyMks0gkuKNPLiUrW1NXXATE1NO0MdTetUiMadBUWZeSUaaRpGppqaXDCOobGmJkQeZgEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

*Test cases taken from [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176738/78039)*

```javascript
a=>eval("for(i=1n;!(''+a**++i).match(a););i")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBDoIwDADQX6nEhJZGguc5v4VmbDozOwKEi/Hbx7i9w/vILqtb4rzdNE@@BFvEPv0uCZuQF4z2ruaCbcvSdcyR@q9s7o1ChkxsqJxJwUJtoPCoGIaTzAQu65qT71N@4Sh4/emfah2BIaASlQM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
->n,i=2{i+=1until/#{n}/=~"#{n**i}";i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ9PWqDpT29awNK8kM0dfuTqvVt@2TglIa2ll1ipZZ9b@1zDU0zMy0NRLTUzOqK7JrClQSIvOjK39DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, 10 bytes

```
@pX søU}a2
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=QHBYIHP4VX1hMg==&input=ODU=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>63</s> 58 bytes

```python
def f(n,e=2):
	while str(n)not in str(n**e):e+=1
	return e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEEXXzSmGbprUEZpIN4V4F6ETG5BJiJHi6WOiLgR3M///9@Izb4FPpazkwElGskYtots3fyO45yRZccjg@fOMI6mFDlaLLlF@JAZ6o2vwuU4rGZPneiIMx/OAzakQetsjxLDXvAVKCeFCAm7edOErSY1GN/wr@uvNjKCnCWH@WZUX)

Python2 would probably be shorter, but I like using 3. Coming up wiht a lambda is difficult, but I'm trying a few things.

Comment: I dont know python but, isn't it shorter using lambda?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I started off trying to do that, but IDLE complained about having a bare `while` in a lambda. Maybe I can try some other ways..

Comment: Maybe some recursive function?

Comment: Defining `e` in the arguments-list (ie. `def f(n,e=2)`) and `n**e` should save some bytes, Python 2 would indeed save quite some bytes.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Lambdas are not like functions. The right hand side of a lambda has to be a single expression, and flow-control commands like `for` or `while` do not work.

Comment: @BMO that's -5, thanks. I forgot about the `**` operator.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｗ∨‹Ｌυ²¬№ＩΠυθ⊞υＩθＩＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDv0jDJ7W4GEjkpZdkaJRq6igYAbFffomGc35pHpBMLC7RCCjKTylNLgFKA@UKNTU1FQJKi4GqdRTA0kARa66AokyYcrhhQPH//w3N/@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ∨‹Ｌυ²¬№ＩΠυθ⊞
```

Repeat until the the list length is at least 2 and its product contains the input...

```
⊞υＩθ
```

... cast the input to integer and push it to the list.

```
ＩＬυ
```

Cast the length of the list to string and implicitly print it.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>104</strike> 89 bytes

```cs
a=>{int i=2;while(!(System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow(a,i)+"").Contains(a+""))i++;return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9fS8MwFMWf009xLQgJnWlX8SnrQAVBUJEp@ByyrF5oE0nSDdn22evtZKAvObn/zo9j4pXxwY5DRNfC23dMtldgOh0j3MI@i0knNPAwOLNAl2ZAzxI20Iy6We6pAGxqtfvEzvIL/nsvX4beBjRR3mH76JJtbZCvfsf1DEWR50Lee5c0usj1VAosChVsGoIDVMdRnalbj2t4pkUu9hnb@MBPQGhgrkgWpFVFv6IQGWO44dSDuoLDgaaXcANNA9U0YgSMvrPyI2CyT@gsrRaQS8hJ6E4IlbGMlSVQUN/3ljjEAzPE5HsK/TWkrCzZxNfEJ7@tDUm@e8p3XfOz/8rq9cmeDOEflOu/QD0Bj8exnv8A)

*-1 byte: changed for loop to while (thanks to [Skidsdev](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/176734/self-contained-powers/176756?noredirect=1#comment425615_176756))*
*-14 bytes: abused C#'s weird string handling to remove* `ToString()` *calls*

Need to use C#'s [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) library, as the standard numeric C# types (int, double, long, ulong, etc.) fail for some larger numbers (including 12, 15, and 17).

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {
    int i = 2;                                          // initialize i

    while( !(System.Numerics.BigInteger.Pow(a,i) + "")  // n = a^i, convert to string
                                .Contains(a + ""))      // if n doesn't contain a
        i++;                                                // increment i

    return i;
}
```

Comment: You can save 1 byte by switching to a [while loop](https://tio.run/##VZBBSwMxEIXP2V8xFoSErdntiqd0CyoIgopYwXNIp3Wgm0iSbZG2v32dVgp6yUtm8t6XiUtXLkQc@kR@BfPvlLEz4NY2JbiFXZGyzeTgofduSj6PgZcZLKEdbDvb8QGobcz2k9YoL37t@qXvMJJL@o5Wjz7jCqN@DVtpx6T0e5jnyCyp9H3w2ZJP0v6pKkVlaSLmPnogcxjM@Q2bQAt4ZoNUu0IsQ5QnPLQwMSxT1rrmXVmqQghaSq5BU8N@z91LuIG2hfrYEgxOYY36I1LGJ/LIV0sYaRixsE8pU4hCVBXw2KHrkDnMA9enHDr@gq8@F1UljnzLfM7bYMw8BY973chz/hvaxSmeA@EfVNq/QHsEHg5DM/kB)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 10 bytes

```
ôkï⌠#k╧▼ï⌠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wluzD6x/1LFDOfjR1@aNpe8Cc//8NuYy4jLlMuEy5zEy5LEy5LE3/AwA)

### Explanation

This feels extremely wasteful, having to read the input explicitly twice, having to increment the loop counter twice.

```
ô            start block of length 6
 k           read integer from input
  ï          index of current loop, or length of last loop
   ⌠         increment twice
    #        pop a, b : push(a**b)
     k       read integer from input
      ╧      pop a, b, a.contains(b)
       ▼     do while false with pop
        ï    index of current loop, or length of last loop
         ⌠   increment twice
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,a=n{(a*=n).to_s=~/#{n}/?2:1+f[n,a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5PJ9E2r1ojUcs2T1OvJD@@2LZOX7k6r1bf3sjKUDstGigfW/tfw1BPz9BAUy83saC6pqKmQCG6QictuiIWKAUA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
i,e=input(),2
while`i`not in`i**e`:e+=1
print e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P1Mn1TYzr6C0RENTx4irPCMzJzUhMyEvv0QhMy8hU0srNcEqVdvWkKugKDOvRCH1/39DAwA)

Inspired by @Gigaflop's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176751/82511).

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 69 <s>81</s> bytes

```
proc S n {incr i
while {![regexp $n [expr $n**[incr i]]]} {}
puts $i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5LioNgEIT33ylqIKusutX2cY4sxUUQSQTHESchAfHs5h9mVUW9qEc/Hcey/vS6aNY2zv2qkdd9nAZtX@063Ib3otOsNuGayPnc/oe6rtu17SzPx69O435M39flbwMnE7koRIhSVKKWaIQb7njyPccLPPASr/A6SQ2ZkQW5kQeFUQRhRFAaZVAZVVAbddAYTSqbkV5c0rH9@AA)

Comment: Same byte count: https://tio.run/##DY7LaoNQFEXn6yt2IKOMzlGPj@/I0DooIs0FY8SmtCB@u72jvdkPWO9xPs91e426a1@UPuSH9t9Hmiftl36bvqa/VddFfdYtm9utT8u4KQ3DkJcH68/7W9d0nPPzc9WiHacQpahEiFo0opXohBvueO69xCs88Bpv8DZHHYVRBKVRBpVRBWFEUBt10BhN0Bpt0BldPpuRKe4Z7Dj/AQ

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell(V3+), 67 bytes

```
function f{param($n)$i=1;do{}until([math]::pow($n,++$i)-match$n)$i}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 78 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(do((e 2(1+ e)))((search(format()"~d"n)(format()"~d"(expt n e)))e)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCsMwFEOvIgwFmS5x9/Yubr5DDXG@cTx08tXTn9KhgwQS781r3uvBVbVi0YaMpWlBQFeEaYIoaH@JHR1uCO4PDBkXZyTNi@UpkZunKJlwY7giee/JPcU2v34yvbnOsP/J9K4d25c/c@SzPg)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 26 bytes

```
2>:@]^:(0=[+/@E.&":^)^:_~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jeysHGLjrDQMbKO19R1c9dSUrOI046zi6yqs/mtypSZn5CsYKdgqpCkYQjimYI4RsoyRKYRnDOaZQDiGhhBdKNrMDbj@AwA)

NOTE: I've changed the final `]` to `x:` in the TIO, to make the tests pass for larger integers.

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 68 bytes

```
select max(level)+1 from dual,t connect by instr(power(x,level),x)=0
```

There is an assumption that source number is stored in a table `t(x)`, e.g.

```
with t as (select 95 x from dual)
```

Test in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> with t as (select 95 x from dual)
  2  select max(level)+1 from dual,t connect by instr(power(x,level),x)=0
  3  /

MAX(LEVEL)+1
------------
          13
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->n{(2..).find{"#{n**_1}"[n.to_s]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3lXXt8qo1jPT0NPXSMvNSqpWUq_O0tOINa5Wi8_RK8uOLY2trIUqXFyi4RRuaxkJ4CxZAaAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 19 bytes

```
J2R@?^jbxq~[_+fi2.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dlPnfyyjIwT4uK6misC46Xjst00hP@39teM5/Qy4jLmMuEy5TLjMucy4LLksuQwMA)

```
J    # Duplicate input
2R@  # Range (2..)
?^   # (in^2, in^3, ...)
j    # Put input to head of stack
bx   # Box
q~[  # Quoted contains
_+   # Push together (contains input)
fi   # Find the index which contains input
2.+  # Add 2 (0-indexed and 1 dropped)
```